# React is rendering old changes in my css file not the new changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

i created a webpage but there is a problem. React is rendering css styles that i didn't add to any of the elements in my css file. I decided to use web developer tool to inspect the site, and i noticed react is rendering changes from an old save in the css file. Basically it's not reacting to new changes made in the css file. Instead it is still rendering the old changes.
like look at the .left div, in the code, it doesn't have a margin but when rendered, it has a margin and a background color

[image: --this is the original code of the css file--]

but this is what happens when it is rendered.
[image: when you check the rendered view in developer's mode , some new styling has been added to it.]

Comment: Any solution? I too have the same problem

Comment: yhhh. the solution is actually to rename your css file to "your_css_file_name".module.css
example home.module.css. This is because the way react works is that it links all the css files. So if you make button{ background-color: blue} in one css file, it affects ALL the buttons in the other pages. using module.css scopes the css file locally

Answer (score 1):

the solution to this is that all the css files in react are linked. so it is using the styling from another css file.
If you want to limit a css file to ONLY  a page, use [page_style_title].module.css instead of [page_style_title].css

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the page with Ctrl + F5 to clear the old caché content.

Comment: yhh i did that. i thought the issue was coming from the web browser. But it isn't. Unfortunately the problem still persists. I even tried different browsers still same results